# Getter and setter methods in a Peewee model

Tags: python, peewee

I have the following simple model in Peewee:

```
class SiteText(BaseModel):
    url = TextField()
    text = TextField()
    my_counter = IntegerField()

    def get_text_by_url(url):
        d = [s.text for s in SiteText.select(SiteText.url == url)]
        d = d[0] if len(d) > 0 else None
        return d

    def save_text(updates):
        # updates is a dict containing, url, text, my_counter
        SiteText.upsert(**updates)

    def get_outage_counter(url):
        c = [c.my_counter for c in SiteText.select(SiteText.url == url)]
        c = c[0] if len(c) > 0 else None
        return c

    def set_outage_counter(url, counter):
        c = SiteText.get(SiteText.url == url)
        c.counter = counter
        c.save()
```

However, it feels rather strange writing getters and setters for some of the attributes. Is there a more Pythonic way of doing this? Should I, for example, have a single method for getting and setting the outage counter for a specified URL? Should I convert the getter and setter functions to properties (though then they would clash with the actual attributes). Feedback welcome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually using properties wouldn't clash with your attribute name, because they can be different than the getter/setter function.

```
class Example:
    def __init__(self):
       self.value = 5

    @property
    def value(self):
        print('Entering value getter')
        return self._value

    @value.setter
    def value(self, val):
        print('Entering value setter')
        self._value = val
```

Lets say we have the class as above. You can see that the getter function is returning `_value` which might be strange for someone who would see that in the `__init__` method there is only `self.value = 5` but not `self._value`.

Lets say that we do this next:

```
a = Example()
```

Just after instantiating the class object, `__init__` is calling the `value.setter` function due to `self.value = 5`, and because of that, we got:

```
a = Example()
Entering value setter
print(a.value)
Entering value getter
5
print(a.__dict__)
{'_value': 5} # _value was created in setter function
```

So as you can see, you can use properties this way and be fine with it.

Comment: Will this work in the DB model as well though? For example, `my_counter` must be defined as a top-level attribute and does not need to be initialized via `__init__`. I think that way it's actually defined as a `Field` class.

Comment: There is a way to use something like `counter = property(getter_func, setter_func, del_func)` and it should allow you to use `obj.counter` which would call the getter_func, or `obj.counter = 5` which would call the setter func, etc.

Comment: Thanks, I opted for a different approach in the end where I modify the model in-place rather than its individual attributes. Nevertheless, your solution might work so accepting as correct answer.

Comment: This way doesn't work with peewee, since it uses class variables

Answer (score 5):

Peewee's `playhouse` extensions includes [hybrid attributes](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/playhouse.html#hybrid-attributes), which is probably what you're looking for. They are basically `@properties`, but modified to work with peewee.

Here's an example from my own code:

```
from peewee import *
from playhouse import hybrid    # <-- imports the hybrid extension

class User(BaseModel):
    username = CharField()
    _password = CharField()    # <-- note the underscore

    # ... other fields come here ...

    @hybrid.hybrid_property
    def password(self):
        return self._password

    @password.setter
    def set_password(self, plaintext):
        self._password = generate_password_hash(plaintext)
```

This is intended to store hashed passwords: so the setter uses a function (`generate_password_hash`) to process the password before it gets stored.

In your case, you'd use your own functions instead

```
class SiteText(BaseModel):
    _counter = IntegerField()

    @hybrid.property
    def counter(self):
        # code to process output can come here
        return _counter

    @counter.setter
    def set_counter(self, counter):
        # code to process counter comes here
        self._counter = counter
```

Then, if `s` is a `SiteData` object, you can run commands like `s.counter = 1`, `print s.counter`, and so on. The data will automatically be preprocessed using the getter and setter before being saved as `_counter` in your object.

Finally, I recommend you don't run `save()` in your getters and setters. Instead, let the properties be saved in the object, and then run `save()` manually to commit them to the database. Otherwise you could end up hitting the database multiple times unnecessarily, or saving something you didn't intend.

Answer (score 1):

Due to the way peewee uses metaclasses and class variables, cannot define your fields in `__init__` you have to alternate the name

```
class SiteText(db.Model):
    url = CharField()    

    @property
    def gs_url(self):
        return self.url

    @gs_url.setter
    def gs_url(self, val):
        self.url = val
```